# How to format datetime based on timezone dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, format, timezone

I have tried different ways to format, but couldn't get what I want.
In my angualr App, I have data from database, like this

```
PacificTime TimeZoneCode    TimeZone
2022-02-16 14:00:00.000 US/Eastern  ET
```

With Kendo format, I was able to convert the time to local time based on the time zone, the result is: Wed Feb 16 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST), but when I applied date pipe, it always convert back to old time. I tried is  date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'  since I need it to be '02/16/2022, 05:00 PM'. I tried other format as well, but none was working. Please tell me which part went wrong, time format, or time zone convert? Below is the code to convert with Kendo.
In ts:

```
    convertTest(dateTime: string, zone: string) {
    const from = new Date(dateTime);
    const to = ZonedDate.fromLocalDate(from, zone)    
    return to
  }
```

in html:

```
{{convertTimezone(dataItem.pacificTime, dataItem.imeZoneCode    ) | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a' }}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: by the way, I don't want the formatted date based on browser or user local. need to be based on time zone from my database. thanks.

Comment: the convert function missed one line. it should be                             
    convertTest(dateTime: string, zone: string) {
    const from = ZonedDate.fromLocalDate(new Date(dateTime), 'US/Pacific');            
    const to = ZonedDate.fromLocalDate(from, zone)    
    return to
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I figured out. I posted it for anyone if having same issue.
I also need to import kendo package.
import '@progress/kendo-date-math/tz/all';
import { IntlService } from "@progress/kendo-angular-intl"

then will get result from
const from: Date = ZonedDate.fromLocalDate(new Date(dateTime), zone);
return this.intl.formatDate(from, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a")

Answer (score 0):

Angular date pipe uses local time zone if not provided.

You can use Angular common formatDate function in your convertTest like this

```
convertTest(dateTime: string, zone: string) {
  return formatDate(dateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a", "en-US", zone);
}
```

Or You can use timezone in date pipe like this

```
{{dataItem.pacificTime | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a' : dataItem.imeZoneCode }}
```

Comment: I tried but none of them work. So the date is 2022-02-16 14:00:00.000, in ET, it should be 2022-02-16 17-00 based on the zone code.  I could get Wed Feb 16 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) from my convertTest. but it always failed to display no matter what format. Is it because of browser? I ran it in PT timezone.